# What are the most commonly used software design patterns?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm sure this depends heavily on a few variables. Here are the ones I can think of:

-Desktop, mobile, web, or server application

-With GUI, without GUI

-Object-oriented, non-object-oriented

-Choice of language

So what design patterns are the most prevalent? Which designs are most advanced? Thanks

Comment: Your question is overly broad and does not lend itself to a precise answer.

Comment: I realize there will be a few different answers, depending on the type of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is quite academic. But I'll give the best answer I can:

The software development process first involves obtaining the set of high level goals, and functional requirements from the stakeholders.

Stakeholders are defined as, the paying client, the end users, your bosses and co-workers involved with the project, and anyone else whom the project will have a direct influence upon.

High level goals are things like, "It needs to be easy to use, because our end users are volunteers with limited computer knowledge" or, "It needs to be completely secure because we are storing sensitive personal information".

Functional requirements are the nitty-gritties. "We need to store information about people. First Name and Surname need to be at least 50 characters... etc.".

And from there you consider the relative strengths and weaknesses of each approach.

You want a mobile app? Strengths include portable and versatile. Weaknesses: Will the end-users even have a phone capable of running the app? Or does the client intend their end-users to only be people with a smartphone?

Without reference to a specific project, I would say that the Goals of the project would affect what platform the application will run upon, and the choice of GUI. And the Functional Requirements would influence the choice of programming language.

So I hope I got my point across: You would be better off getting a broad understanding of the strengths and weaknesses of each technology and approach, and it is simply a mark of a professional to be able to correctly apply them to each project you came across, often negotiating these strengths, weaknesses and associated costs with the client.